# php regex selecting url from html source

Tags: php, regex

I'm new to stackoverflow and from South Korea.

I'm having difficulties with regex with php.

I want to select all the urls from user submitted html source.

The restrictions I want to make are following.

Select urls EXCEPT

- urls are within  tags
  for example if the html source is like below,

  `<a href="http://aaa.com">http://aaa.com</a>`

  Neither of `http://aaa.com` should be selected.
- urls right after " or =

Here is my current regex stage.

`/(?<![\"=])https?\:\/\/[^\"\s<>]+/i`

but with this regex, I can't achieve the first rule.

I tried to add negative lookahead at the end of my current regex like

`/(?<![\"=])https?\:\/\/[^<>\"\s]+(?!<\/a>)/i`

It still chooses the second url in the a tag like below.

`http://aaa.co`

We don't have developers Q&A community like Stackoverflow in Korea, so I really hope someone can help this simplely looking regex issue!

Comment: The _real_ issue you have is that you're not choosing the right tool for the job. Parsing HTML with regex is not a good idea, use a parser [like `DOMDocument`](http://www.php.net/DOMDocument)

Comment: Thanks for the response Elias, but even if I use those kind fo parsing class, shouldn't I still have to retrieve url from text in some way? I'm kind of learning regex so I'm just looking for some help solving this issue with regex.

Comment: Well of course you extract the url from the markup: `$links = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');` gives you all the link elements. Then simply loop over them, and get the links by doing `$link->getAttribute('href')->value;`. If certain url's should be skipped, then _that's_ where a regex fits in. To get the link text: `$link->nodeValue` should work

Comment: Elias, I guess my question is mistaken. I'm not choosing href withi the A tag. I'm want to select urls EXCEPT the urls within A tags.

Comment: Added answer: you can get at the textContent of a node through the `textContent` property of an instance of `DOMNode`, or you can simply strip away the markup tags of your HTML, by calling `strip_tags`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing as you're not trying to extract urls that are the `href` attribute of an `a` node, you'll want to start by getting the actual *text content* of the dom. This can be easily done like so:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($htmlString);
$root = $dom->getElementsByTagName('body')[0];//get outer tag, in case of a full dom, this is body
$text = $root->textContent;//no tags, no attributes, no nothing.
```

An alternative approach would be this:

```
$text = strip_tags($htmlString);//gets rid of makrup.
```

Comment: Thank you Elias! I couldn't come up with the strip_tags functionallity ! I think that could solve my situation. However, I will definitely look into the first one.

Comment: @user3859822: happy to help. Looking into the entire `DOMDocument` business is definitely worth while. The API feels clunky at times, but it is the only way to write reliable code that processes markup.

Answer (score 1):

Seriously consider using PHP's [DOMDocument](http://php.net/DOMDocument) class. It does reliable HTML parsing. Doing this with regular expressions is error prone, more work, and slower.

The DOM works just like in the browser and you can use `getElementsByTagName` to get all links.

I got your use case working with this code using the DOM (try it here: http://3v4l.org/5IFof):

```
<?php

$html = <<<HTML
<a href="http://aaa.com">http://aaa.com</a>
HTML;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);

foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $link) {
    var_dump($link->getAttribute('href'));
    // Output: http://aaa.com
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply chh. but I guess my question is mistaken. I'm not choosing href withi the A tag. I'm want to select urls EXCEPT urls within A tags.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use Regex. Use DOM

```
$html = '<a href="http://aaa.com">http://aaa.com</a>';
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $a) {
    if($a->hasAttribute('href')){
        echo $a->getAttribute('href');
    }
    //$a->nodeValue; // If you want the text in <a> tag
}
```

Comment: I guess my question is mistaken. I'm not choosing href withi the A tag. I'm want to select urls EXCEPT urls within A tags.